# как сделать клик по слайдеру картинок что бы открыть картинку в полный экран

Tags: android, slider, android-on-click

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider
пользуюсь этой библиотекой не как не могу повесить клик на слайдер что бы открывать картинку в полный экран пробывал так

```
  mDemoSlider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Log.d("mylog","click click");
            }
        });
```

клик не обрабатывается

Comment: Судя по примеру вам надо на TextSliderView вешать слушатель нажатий

Comment: можно пример кода всю голову изломал на что тоак не вешал слушатель не кликается и все((

Comment: Покажите как пытались, покажите разметку там, адаптера, вот это всё. Пример дать не могу - т.к. ни разу либу не юзал.